# How to check if Spring boot is running in standalone or embedded mode?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there some reliable way how to check if spring boot is running in JAR (standalone with embedded tomcat) or WAR (in j2ee server) mode?

Answer (score 7):

There's no built in API to check which environment you're running in. Probably the most robust way would be to use different configuration for your application depending on whether it's started via its main method or via its `SpringBootServletInitializer` subclass. Exactly what you should do depends on your reason for needing to know and also personal preference.

For example, you could configure a property that you can the query via the `Environment`, using `@Value`, etc:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ExampleApplication.class).properties(
                "com.example.mode:servlet-container");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ExampleApplication.class).properties(
                "com.example.mode:standalone").run(args);
    }

}
```

Another option would be to provide a configuration class in addition to `ExampleApplication.class` that's different depending on what mode you're running in:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ExampleApplication.class, 
                ServletContainerConfiguration.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ExampleApplication.class,
                StandaloneConfiguration.class).run(args);
    }

}
```

Exactly what you do in `ServletContainerConfiguration` or `StandaloneConfiguration` is then up to you. You could, for example, publish a bean that remembers the mode and then query it whenever you need to know.

Yet another option would be to activate different profiles depending on the mode.