# How to get current SpringApplication instance in spring-boot programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to get current SpringApplication instance in spring-boot programmatically?
As spring docs says : SpringApplication has a method called `isWebEnvironment()` . I don't know how to tell if an application is a web or non-web application programmtically , can I get it from  `ApplicationContext.getEnvironment()` ? By the way , I don't want to solve this by searching `xxServlet` like `HttpServletRequest` ... etc.

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884708/how-to-check-if-spring-boot-is-running-in-standalone-or-embedded-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>What about `applicationContext instanceof WebApplicationContext`?</del>

If you're trying to simply determine whether or not your application is running in a web context, then you can use the fact that when a Spring application is started in a web context, the `ApplicationContext` object you have access to is an instance of the `WebApplicationContext` interface. Therefore you can simply write

```
isWebEnvironment = (applicationContext instanceof WebApplicationContext);
```

There is no real reason to get the `SpringApplication` object from your class, as its sole purpose is to build an `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13602589)

Comment: This actually is an answer to the question -- I will edit to clarify.

Comment: Well, it's a very simple way . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Spring Boot` you can use this:

```
String[] springBootAppBeanName = applicationContext.getBeanNamesForAnnotation(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication.class);
applicationContext.getBean(springBootAppBeanName[0]);
```

This will retrieve the spring bean names who are annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, after get them you can simple get the instance by his name.

Comment: Because of this I started my answer with `If you are using Spring Boot`...

Comment: @HimanshuAhire, and why this question has the tag spring-boot?